# Visual Studio Code: I lost the built-in CodeLens tools to resolve merge conflicts from Git

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code 1.70 when viewing a file with Git merge conflict markers, I no longer get the blue/green highlighting nor the "Accept Current Changes..." CodeLens choices, even though setting "Merge-conflict › Code Lens" is enabled. Any idea how to fix?

example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 1.71.0 and it fixed the issue.  Maybe a bug with the new merge features in 1.70?

Comment: It probably was intentional. They introduced a 3-way merge editor (not sure why it didn't come up for you) instead of the tool you've been using, but now the old thing was re-added back.

Comment: Link: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_merge-editor-improvements:~:text=RESTORING%20OLD%20CONFLICT%20DECORATORS

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall GitLens. Close and restart Visual Studio Code. Should fix it. Can re-install GitLens afterward.

Comment: I've never installed GitLens and I didn't think it was necessary, as the Code Lens feature is built-in to VS Code.  I tried installing GitLens anyway, but it didn't help.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Shucks. I'll leave my answer is case it helps others. Looks like you fixed it yourself in other answer (upgrade VS Code).